# does $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{3^{n-1}+1}{3^n} $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is the Series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{3^{n-1}+1}{3^n} $$
we can simplify this series into $1/3$ and $1/3^n$ then $1/3$ is convergent and $1/3^n$ is also convergent by Geometric test or ratio test . convergent + convergent is also convergent but the solution manual says its divergent by divergence test $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{n-1}+1}{3^n}=\frac{1}{3}$ not equal to $0$ , how can it be convergent and divergent at the same time ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $\sum_n\frac13$ diverges.

Answer (score 3):

If you "simplify" the series, you get:
$$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{3^{n-1}+1}{3^n}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac13+\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{3^n} $$
But the first series is divergent, so your argument is not correct.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1824226.